# Understanding Selection Theorems

Tags: general-topology, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Can someone explain me what is the role of Selection Theorems?
Especially; what is the point of the Continuous Selection Theorems for the set valued mappings? Is it just to guarantee a fixed point?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some context for your question.  For a start, a statement of the selection theorem (or theorems) in which you are interested would be quite helpful, as well as some explanation of what is confusing you.

Comment: They can be seen as generalisations of the Tietze extension theorem, e.g. They can characterise ordered compact spaces etc. It's not always about fixpoints.